# Jquery loop through table select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that shows some information of tickets

check this for the html of table. [Check this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p7d22Lgy/)

how can I loop through each select box click?, select box i.e rows will varies.

please give me some hints.

thank you...

```
<table id="tableTickets" class="table table-striped custab">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Ticket Type </th>
            <th> REMAINING </th>
            <th> Price </th>
            <th> Quantity </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="ticketRow1">
            <td id="tdTicketName1">
                <input type="hidden" id="ticketId" name="ticketId" value="1">
                <h4 class="heading1">Name1</h4>
            </td>
            <td id="tdTicketQuantity1">
                100 </td>
            <td id="tdTicketPrice1">
                <div id="divTicketPrice1">12.30</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control" name="ticketQty" id="ticketQty1" style="height:30px;">
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="ticketRow2">
            <td id="tdTicketName2">
                <input type="hidden" id="ticketId" name="ticketId" value="2">
                <h4 class="heading1">Name2</h4>
            </td>
            <td id="tdTicketQuantity2">
                200 </td>
            <td id="tdTicketPrice2">
                <div id="divTicketPrice2">12.34</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control" name="ticketQty" id="ticketQty2" style="height:30px;">
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="ticketRow3">
            <td id="tdTicketName3">
                <input type="hidden" id="ticketId" name="ticketId" value="3">
                <h4 class="heading1">Name1</h4>
            </td>
            <td id="tdTicketQuantity3">
                100 </td>
            <td id="tdTicketPrice3">
                <div id="divTicketPrice3">23.52</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control" name="ticketQty" id="ticketQty3" style="height:30px;">
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="ticketRow4">
            <td id="tdTicketName4">
                <input type="hidden" id="ticketId" name="ticketId" value="4">
                <h4 class="heading1">Name2</h4>
            </td>
            <td id="tdTicketQuantity4">
                200 </td>
            <td id="tdTicketPrice4">
                <div id="divTicketPrice4">15.41</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control" name="ticketQty" id="ticketQty4" style="height:30px;">
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" style="text-align:right;">
                <h4 class="heading1">Total <div id="ticketPriceTotal" class="col-sm-12">000</div></h4>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: $('#tableTickets').find('select') would select all select boxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check code on fiddle. with below code you can get each select box "onchange" or "onclick" event.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p7d22Lgy/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('select').on('change',function(){
     alert($(this).val())
   })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
first give class to to price <div class="price"></div> and then write code given bellow,

$(document).on("change",".form-control",function(){
var total=0;
$("tbody tr").each(function(){

var price=$(this).find(".price").text();
var tickets=$(this).find(".form-control").val();

total=parseFloat(total)+(parseFloat(price)*parseFloat(tickets));
})
alert(total);

});
```